# Java Swing setting JPanel Size

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

Could anyone point out where I am going wrong with this java swing gui code. I am trying to add two buttons to a JPanel and then add it into a frame after setting the size but it seems to not be responding to the `setSize` values passed to it

```
public Test() {
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, 2);
    //this.setLayout(layout);
    this.setSize(700, 700);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setSize(new Dimension(30, 100));

    JButton rectButton = new JButton("Rectangle");
    JButton ovalButton = new JButton("Oval");
    buttonPanel.add(rectButton);
    buttonPanel.add(ovalButton);
    this.add(buttonPanel);
    this.add(new PaintSurface());
    this.setVisible(true);  
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You're using a GridLayout, but are adding a PaintSurface to BorderLayout.CENTER. You shouldn't be setting sizes. Let the layout decide what the appropriate size is based on the sizes of the components it lays out.

Comment: That edit wasn't good either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not answer your immediate question...but...

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, 2);
this.setLayout(layout);
// You're original code...
// Why are you using `BorderLayout.CENTER` on a `GridLayout`
this.add(new PaintSurface(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You set the layout as a `GridLayout`, but you are using `BorderLayout` constraints to apply one of the components??

Also, make sure that there are not calls to `Test#pack` else where in your code, as this will override the values of `setSize`

**UPDATED (from changes to question)**

Remember, the default layout manager for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, so even though you're calling `buttonPanel.setSize`, it's likely that it's begin overridden by the layout manager anyway.

I would take a read through [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to find a layout manager that best meets your requirements.

If you can't find a single one, consider using compound components with different layout managers to bring the layout closer to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

According to your updated answer, you are not setting your layout on anything.

Anyway, if you use LayoutManager's (which you should), it is pointless to call `setSize()/setBounds()/setLocation()` since it will be overriden by the LayoutManager (that is actually its job).

And guessing that your `Test` class extends `JFrame`, by calling `this.add(buttonPanel); this.add(new PaintSurface());` you are adding two components with the same constraint (`BorderLayout.CENTER`, since `BorderLayout` is the default LayoutManager of the content pane of the `JFrame`) to the content pane.

Consider reading the [LayoutManager tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Just for information, although far from perfect, this shows something "working":

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel buttonPanel;

    public class PaintSurface extends JButton {
        public PaintSurface() {
            super("Paint surface dummy");
        }
    }

    public Test() {
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, 2);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        this.setSize(700, 700);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setSize(new Dimension(30, 100));

        JButton rectButton = new JButton("Rectangle");
        JButton ovalButton = new JButton("Oval");
        buttonPanel.add(rectButton);
        buttonPanel.add(ovalButton);
        this.add(buttonPanel);
        this.add(new PaintSurface());
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll just give you a solution:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Cobie extends JFrame{
    JButton rectButton = new JButton("Rectangle");
    JButton ovalButton = new JButton("Oval");

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel paintSurface = new JPanel();

    public Cobie(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        paintSurface.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        buttonPanel.add(rectButton);
        buttonPanel.add(ovalButton);
        add(buttonPanel);
        add(paintSurface);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Cobie c = new Cobie();
                c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                c.setSize(600,400); //Avoid using this method
                c.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```